# Finite Galois extension and splitting fields relationship

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

suppose E/F is a finite Galois extension. What I need to show that $E$ is $ \operatorname{Split}_F(p_1(x),p_2(x), .. p_n(x))$ for some separable polynomials $p_1(x),··· , p_n(x)\in F[X]$ over $F$.

My attempt. Since  $E/F$ is a finite extension then I can write $E=F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,... \alpha_n)$ . Take  the corresponding minimal polynomials $p_1=p_{\alpha1}, p_2=p_{\alpha2}, ... p_n=p_{\alpha n}$. since $E/F$ is Galois all polynomials splits in $F$  (normality) and they are also separable. Hence $E$ is the splitting field of $p_1,…,p_n$ because the splitting field contains $\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n$ and they generate $E$.

Is my logic correct? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Help for what? ${}{}{}$

Comment: is my logic correct? sorry I have forgot to state that.

Comment: It depends which part is unclear to you.

Comment: The last part concluding that E is the splitting field of p1,.. pn

Comment: $E/F$ normal means that the conjugates of the $\alpha_j$ are in $E$, so you can add them into your list of elements generating $E$. Whence $E$ is the generated by all the roots of the $p_i$.

Comment: that is what I was looking for adding also the other conjugates and roots. Thank you very much I forgot the normality and conjugate relationship!